# UWP VLCMediaElement takeSnapshot() - no file created

Tags: c#, uwp, vlc

I want to process an (RTSP) stream from an IP camera in an UWP app which every x seconds grabs and analyses an image. The simpliest way I found is to use `VLCMediaElement` [(github)](https://github.com/kakone/VLC.MediaElement). My idea is to use `vlcel.MediaPlayer.takeSnapshot()` method to save the image to a file, reload it and then process it.
When I try to use this method no file is created.

```
vlcMediaElement.MediaPlayer.takeSnapshot(1, "e:\\img", 1280, 738);
// or
vlcMediaElement.MediaPlayer.takeSnapshot(1, "ms-appdata:///local/image", 1280, 738);
```

If I try to use the full path to the folder I obtain the same result - no file created.

```
var fldr = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
var img = fldr.CreateFolderAsync("image", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists).GetResults();
vlcMediaElement.MediaPlayer.takeSnapshot(1, img.Path, 1280, 738);
```

Does someone have any idea of what I'm doing wrong (some inputs required to manifest, some options to media instance, etc)?

Comment: Could you give me the code that you read RTSP stream from IP camera?